# Replacing substrings in Matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, substring

In Matlab I have a string, that represents a function. Let it be something like that `'...sin(arcsin(f_2))...'`. I want to find all appearances of `'sin(arcsin(F))'` for any F and replace it with simple `'F'`.

I don't know what kind of function if F. It may be `'exp'` or `'cos'` or something else.

How can I do it? Is it any smart way to do it without while-loop?

Comment: There is a built in function for that: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html

Comment: How do you generate these strings? Can't it be easier to prevent the creation of this (and similar) constructions in the first place? I suspect you could use something like `simplify` here to get rid of it...

Comment: ...`sym/simplify` that is

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis, you're right, but it was supposed to be true

Comment: @restrest: Nevermind, I'm actually not so sure about the inequality. I numerically verified my statement, but then I started suspecting I was looking at numerical artefacts rather than mathematical truths...

Comment: @restrest: But, how do you generate these strings?

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis, I write them by fingers:)

Comment: @restrest: ...why not correct them with fingers too? :)

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis, in this way I won't be able do it for generated strings:)

Comment: @restrest: If you have the symbolic toolbox, you can also use `char(sym(str))`; apparently, this automatically gets rid of self-inverted things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways:

```
>> char(sym(str))  %// requires symbolic toolbox

>> regexprep(str, 'sin\(arcsin\(F\)\)', 'F')

>> strrep(str, 'sin(arcsin(F))', 'F')
```

The nice thing about the `regexprep` method is that you can be a lot more flexible with regard to spacing and casing:

```
>> regexprep(str, 'sin\s*\(\s*a(rc)*sin\s*\(\s*F\s*\)\s*\)', 'F', 'ignorecase')
```

the call above will convert all of the following:

```
>> str = ' sin (    arcsin(F )  )'
>> str = 'sin(arCSin(f) )'
>> str = '   Sin             (arcsin(f)  )       )'
>> str = 'Sin(Asin(f)))'
```

etc.

Note that for both methods above: `str` may be either a string or cell array of strings.

***EDIT***

You have indicated that `F` may be anything. That complicates matters. For simple matches you could still use something like

```
>> regexprep(str, 'sin\s*\(\s*a(rc)*sin\s*\(\s*(.+)\s*\)\s*\)', '$2', 'ignorecase')
```

But you'll have to be careful, because things like

```
>> str = 'acos(log( sin(arcsin( exp(x) )) * sin(x) ))'
```

will be incorrectly converted :

```
>> regexprep(str, 'sin\s*\(\s*a(rc)*sin\s*\(\s*(.+)\s*\)\s*\)', '$2', 'ignorecase')
ans = 
    acos(log( exp(x) )) * sin(x)
```

(note the incorrect bracketing). One solution is to use lazy operators:

```
>> regexprep(str, 'sin\s*\(\s*a(rc)*sin\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*\)', '$2', 'ignorecase')
```

but beware that you're *really* crossing over the border of what regular expressions can (or *should*) be used for. Not *all* possible cases will be handled successfully this way...See also [this legendary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1085062)

The best way by far is to prevent these strings from being generated that way in the fist place. I suspect that a simple `sym/simplify` will do away with this whole problem.

Comment: but how to make it works for any F. I don't know the appearance of F. It may be exponent or cos or smth

Comment: @restrest: Then you'll have to do something else; see my edits.